# Modem, router, LAN and WAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a problem: My modem uses 3 ports: 1 port is empty, 1 port connects to the TV, 1 port connects to the xiaomi wireless router. Now my PC is connecting to the Xiaomi router via the LAN port by wire. The problem here: if I let the TV connect wirelessly to the Xiaomi router too, the TV and the PC will recognize each other as local area network (LAN). But if I connect the TV to the modem (via wire), the PC and the TV will recognize each other as WAN (even they use the same modem). Is there a way to connect the TV to the modem and the PC to the xiaomi router and those two devices will recognize each other as LAN?

Comment: We need more information, including the make and model of your modem, as well as how the ports are connected up.   That said, assuming your modem is actually a router (which is likely), can you configure your Xiaomi as an Access point (ie ignore its WAN interface and disable its DHCP server)

Comment: Put a switch on wireless router to add LAN ports on the wireless router.  Turn wireless OFF on the modem and just use your own wireless router for Wifi